# How to customize authentification page/location

Tags: grails, spring-security

How can I customize/modify/move the authentification page of Spring security (grails) ? where can I get its default code?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is where you can find the plugin source file:

```
plugins\spring-security-core<version-number>\grails-app\login\auth.gsp
```

Copy the source file and place it in:

```
grails-app\Views\login\auth.gsp
```

This way your updates will overwrite the origin.

Comment: thank you but I can't find the plugins folder, can you help me please?

Comment: In your IDE grails view you should be able to find all plugins; otherwise look into `work` folder.

Comment: I'm using NETBEANS and I can't find "plugins" in view, and the "work" doesn't exist :/

Comment: In Intellij there is a "targetIdea\work" folder. Even in Netbeans there should be folder the loads all the plugins

Answer (score 0):

You need to put following code into your custom gsp :

```
<input type='text' name='j_username'/>
<input type='password' name='j_password'/>
```

Comment: can you give me the source please? their should be other things (like the error messages...)

Comment: for example https://github.com/etcpe9/example/blob/master/grails-app/views/login/auth.gsp